# I can't perform an operation on the link text with Flutter web app getInitialLink

Tags: flutter, dart

I will redirect to my web application written with flutter with the links I will give to the users by creating manually (qr code), but the problem is that the address of this site that I deployed with firebase is as follows; https://web-app-30399.web.app I will give some of the users a link like this; https://web-report-45387.web.app?745763098258940780594 because the id after the question mark will be the id of a document in the firestore. when the user opens this site, I want the application to take the part of the application after "?" in this link and reach that document. I tried a little but I couldn't succeed. after deploying, I get the error in the picture.

```
Future<void> getLocationId() async {
    String? link = await getInitialLink();
    initialLink.value = link as String;
    initialLink.value = Uri.parse(initialLink.value).query;
    if (initialLink.value == "") {
      initialLink.value = "FJ9ISNeHjkbD5Uok5Eco";
    }
  }
```

```
Future<void> initializeAndGetLocationAndProjectDoc(String id) async {
    await getLocationId();
    await getLocationAndProjectDoc(initialLink.value);
  }
```

```
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FirstPage({super.key});
  final projectServiceController = Get.put(ProjectService());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: projectServiceController.initializeAndGetLocationAndProjectDoc(
              projectServiceController.initialLink.value),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Hata: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                      '${projectServiceController.projectName.value}'),
                  Text(
                      '${projectServiceController.locationName.value}'),
                  
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmWiE.png)